# Show that $\int_{0}^{\pi\over 2}\arctan(\tan^8{(\pi^2{x}}))\mathrm dx={5\over 4}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can anyone help to provide a proof for $(1)$? Pleases! Thank you.

$$\int_{0}^{\pi\over 2}\arctan(\tan^8{(\pi^2{x}}))\mathrm dx={5\over 4}\tag1$$

Enforcing $u=\tan^8{(\pi^2{x})}$ then $du={8\over \pi^2}\tan^7{(\pi^2{x})}\sec^2{(\pi^2{x})}dx$

Recall: $1+\tan^2{x}=\sec^2{x}$

$du={8\over \pi^2}\tan^7{(\pi^2{x})}+{8\over \pi^2}\tan^8{(\pi^2{x})}dx$

$${\pi^2\over 8}\int_{0}^{k}\arctan{u}\cdot{\mathrm du\over u+u^{7/8}}$$

$k=\arctan{\left(\tan^8{\left(\pi^3\over 2\right)}\right)}$

This is where I got so far. Can't go any further.

Extra note

I think this is the correct version

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi\over 2}\arctan(\tan^{2n}{(\pi^2{x}}))\mathrm dx={5\over 4}\tag2$$

Comment: Please take care of the limits of integration. When $x $ goes from $ 0 \to \frac {\pi}{2} $, $u $ goes from $0 \to \arctan (\tan^8 (\pi^3/2)) $.

Comment: I think this is wrong. Numerically I get 1.249999992164761... instead of 5/4. Please can anybody confirm this?

Comment: @Nemo confirmed: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NIntegrate%5BArcTan%5BTan%5E8%5BPi%5E2+x%5D%5D,%7Bx,0,Pi%2F2%7D,WorkingPrecision-%3E32%5D

Because there is nothing special about $\tan(\pi^3/2)$ such a simple result would be a real suprise

Comment: Here is an explanation why this integral is so close to $5/4$ but not equal to $5/4$. Let's rewrite it as
$$
I=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\pi^3\over 2}\arctan(\tan^8{({x}})) dx.
$$
It is known that 
$$
\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{5\pi}\arctan(\tan^8{({x}})) dx=5/4.
$$ Then due to $\pi^2\approx 10$
$$
I=\frac54+\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{5\pi}^{\pi^3\over 2}\arctan(\tan^8{({x}})) dx\approx\frac54+\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^{{\pi^3\over2}-5\pi }x^8 dx=5/4+\frac{({\pi^3/2}-5\pi )^9}{9\pi^2}=1.24999999285...
$$
which is pretty close to the numerical value 1.249999992164761...

Answer (score 2):

We can solve this using our friend, the dominated convergence theorem. $\tan^{-1}(x) \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, so the integrand satisfies the conditions for the theorem. Let $u = \pi^2x$ and apply d.c. by moving the limit in.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan^{-1}(\tan^{2n}(\pi^2 x)) dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi^3}{2}} \tan^{-1}(\tan^{2n}(u)) du$$
$$= \frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi^3}{2}} \tan^{-1}(\lim_{n\to\infty}(\tan^{2}(u))^n) du$$
Depending on the value of u, the inside of the arctangent will either be $0$, $1$, or $\infty$. In other words, the function we are integrating only takes on the constant values $0$, $\frac{\pi}{4}$, or $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (we actually don't care about the middle value since it only happens on a set of measure zero). Taking the limit, we get a rectangle function centered at every odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$, with height and width $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Such a function is $\pi$-periodic. $$\frac{9\pi}{2} < \frac{\pi^3}{2} < 5\pi$$ so we obtain the full area of 5 of the squares (the only piece cut off has height zero). Thus
$$= \frac{1}{\pi^2}5*(\frac{\pi}{2})^2 = \frac{5}{4}$$